How can I remove this circular dependency error from this old Springboot application I am updating?
I have had a look at other similar questions on StackOverflow and have not found any answers that work. I am updating an older Spring boot application which worked fine, however when updating it to 2.7.18 it has complained about circular dependencies.
The original code can be found on Github here:
https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/SACS-Java/blob/dependabot/maven/org.springframework-spring-core-5.2.24.RELEASE/README.md
I have managed to fix one however im stuck on the more complicated A -> B -> C to A circular dependency. Here are the 3 pieces of code causing the circular dependency:
@Service
public class SessionPool {

https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/SACS-Java/blob/fc3654b1f332652a1ae3124900037f4694d1df3b/soap/src/main/java/com/sabre/api/sacs/soap/pool/SessionPool.java
@Controller
@Scope("prototype")
public class SessionCreateWrapper extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/SACS-Java/blob/fc3654b1f332652a1ae3124900037f4694d1df3b/soap/src/main/java/com/sabre/api/sacs/soap/session/SessionCreateWrapper.java
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class SessionCreateInterceptor extends AbstractSessionInterceptor {

https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/SACS-Java/blob/fc3654b1f332652a1ae3124900037f4694d1df3b/soap/src/main/java/com/sabre/api/sacs/soap/interceptor/SessionCreateInterceptor.java
I have tried creating a session manager interface to decouple the dependencies
public interface SessionManager {
    void addToPool(Security session);
    Security getFromPool(SharedContext context);
}

Implementing the SessionManager interface in SessionPool
So that SessionCreateWrapper depends on SessionManager
SessionCreateInterceptor implements SessionManager
But then I get this error:     Parameter 0 of constructor in com.sabre.api.sacs.soap.session.SessionCreateWrapper required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - sessionCreateInterceptor: defined in file [C:\CODE\SACS-Java\soap\target\classes\com\sabre\api\sacs\soap\interceptor\SessionCreateInterceptor.class]
    - sessionPool: defined in file [C:\CODE\SACS-Java\soap\target\classes\com\sabre\api\sacs\soap\pool\SessionPool.class]

I have also tried using setter injection but that just changes the circular dependency. The error is:
  workflowTrigger (field private com.sabre.api.sacs.soap.pool.SessionPool com.sabre.api.sacs.flowtrigger.WorkflowTrigger.sessionPool)
┌─────┐
|  sessionPool
└─────┘

Of course the code works if I use spring.main.allow-circular-references=true but I don't want to use that as advised. Please Help!

If refactoring your code to get rid of this circular dependency is not an option, you can solve it by using the @Lazy injection in one of your beans.
See this answer for reference.

I added @Lazy but it didnt work. Am I putting it in the correct place?
@ Lazy
@ Autowired
SessionPool sessionPool;

@Solv_it_kas yes, I meant @Lazy @Autowired. What the error message says when you put @Lazy on it? Does it still complain about circular dependency or 'more than one bean found'?

Added the notation to the Interceptor class. The error that I now get is:
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:
workflowTrigger (field private com.sabre.api.sacs.soap.pool.SessionPool com.sabre.api.sacs.flowtrigger.WorkflowTrigger.sessionPool)
┌─────┐
|  sessionPool
└─────┘
Which doesn't seem to make sense to my limited Spring knowledge.

@Autowired
public SessionCreateWrapper(@Qualifier("sessionPool") SessionManager sessionManager) {
 this.sessionManager = sessionManager;
}

This could maybe resolve the issue since spring found same type of multiple beans and there is a need for autowiring, you would use @Qualifier to specify the exact bean you would want to inject.

Thanks but i'm no longer using that piece of code. Only the original 3 classes mentioned in the question.
